# How to search characters between #, but do not use # in combination &#60 in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I need help with this Regex.
I have string:

> `text1#text2&#60&#61#text3#56&*()_!`

**I have to get:** `text1`, `text2&#60&#61`, `text3`, `56&*()_!`

How to search characters between #, but do not use # in combination `&#60` and `&#61` (pattern: `&#\d+`)
The regular expression will be used in C#.

Now I use this pattern `.*?(?=#)|.*?$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank a lot for your answer, but I found the best way

```
string value = "text1#text2&#60&#61#text3#56&*()_!";
string splitPattern = @"(?<!&)#|#(?!\d+)";

List<string> values = Regex.Split(value, splitPattern).Where(s => s != String.Empty);
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: And why is this better?

Comment: I want to handle all cases.
I need to split a string by the symbol #, but do not take it in a combination of characters ?#60. I use only numbers (pattern: ?#\d+). 
If the string is &#, then I must split the string according to # and get &. If the string is #60, I must get 60. My pattern (?<!&)#|#(?!\d+) is handled correctly all cases

Answer (score 2):

Just split the string according to `#` which was preceded by a number.

```
string value = "text1#text2&#60&#61#text3#56&*()_!";
string[] lines = Regex.Split(value, @"(?<=\d)#");
foreach (string line in lines) {
Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/kVUTs0)

Comment: I think the regex Regex.Split(value,@"(?<=\w)#"); might be more appropriate, should in case the OP gets string that are not terminated by numbers eg text1a#

Comment: @Agdelis May i know the reason for unaccepting my answer.

Comment: @Avinash Raj You answer solved the problem, but this is a special case. If you will split a line &# or #60, then you solution solution does not work.